# How to set a global variable in app.module.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseUI for an app and I want to set a sort of global variable that holds is the user is new.

I have set the firebaseAuthConfig in app.module.ts, as in the documentation is and everything works good. I can create accounts, login,...

I can also see if the user is new.

My problem is that I cannot send this data forward. In some parts of the app, I want to be able to show different data if the user is new.

I tried to send the isNewUser value in providers but I get an error saying the object is undefined.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { firebase, firebaseui, FirebaseUIModule } from 'firebaseui-angular';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';

let newUser;

const firebaseUiAuthConfig: firebaseui.auth.Config = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
      this.newUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
      console.log("NEW USER", newUser);

      authResult.user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
        console.log("TOKEN", token);
      })

      return true;
    }
  },
  signInSuccessUrl: "/tabs/discover",
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInOptions: [
    {
      requireDisplayName: true,
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    }
  ],
  tosUrl: '<your-tos-link>',
  privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacyPolicyUrl-link>',
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FirebaseUIModule.forRoot(firebaseUiAuthConfig)
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    { provide: 'newUser', useValue: this.newUser }   // provide newUser to be used from other sections of the app
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The { provide: 'newUser', useValue: this.newUser } should provide the value I need but it doesn't work. If I use a static string, it works. Somehting like { provide: 'newUser', useValue: 'text' }

On some other page, I have an injector code.

```
const isNewUser = this.injector.get('newUser');
```

I get the value here (if I use the string), although injector.get() is deprecated.

But that doesn't help me because I need to send the this.newUser value, not a static text.

```
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
          this.newUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
          console.log("NEW USER", newUser);
    
          authResult.user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
            console.log("TOKEN", token);
          })
    
          return true;
        }
```

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Regards,
AG

Answer (score 0):

you can store a global variable using the [service feature of angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). For example:

Create a service component, called **account.service.ts** and store a variable called `isUserNew`. Make sure to change this variable depending on whether the user is new or not.
Run the command: `ng g s services/account` to generate the service.

**account.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
public export AccountService {
    public isUserNew = false;
}
```

In your other components, you can use this service by injecting it through the constructor

**component.ts:**

```js
constructor(public account: AccountService) {}
```

Now, you can access the `isUserNew` in that component by doing `account.isUserNew`

Comment: Hi. I already have some services. My issue is to send a variable data from app.module.ts, where the firebaseUi config is. I can see only in the callback if a user is new or not. And the callback is in app.module.ts.